# How to use SQL to select XML columns with a root node?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to retrieve some XML columns from an SQL database, surrounded by a "root" node, but am finding it difficult to find the correct syntax.

Basically, I have details in an XML column, and I would like to get a single XML result back that groups all the columns as child nodes of a parent node.

So... given this:

```
declare @changes table (order_no varchar(10), details xml)

insert into @changes values ('123', null)
insert into @changes values ('456', null)

update @changes set details = '<ORDER><ORDER_ID>' + order_no + '</ORDER_ID></ORDER>'
```

...I would like to generate XML like this...

```
<ORDERS>
  <ORDER>
    <ORDER_ID>123</ORDER_ID>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
    <ORDER_ID>456</ORDER_ID>
  </ORDER>
</ORDERS>
```

I thought it would be a variation of the "root" clause, in order to get the root node to be "ORDERS", but I cannot seem to get rid of the "details" parent nodes around each "record". ie.

```
select details
from @changes
for xml path(''), root('ORDERS')
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have done what I needed in the following way, but is this the best way?

```
select details.query('/ORDER')
from @changes
for xml path(''), root('ORDERS')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the XML column.

```
DECLARE @changes TABLE (order_no VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @changes VALUES ('123')
INSERT INTO @changes VALUES ('456')

SELECT order_no AS ORDER_ID
FROM @changes
FOR XML PATH('ORDER'), ROOT('ORDERS')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21402)**

**Result  :**

```
<ORDERS>
  <ORDER>
    <ORDER_ID>123</ORDER_ID>
  </ORDER>
  <ORDER>
    <ORDER_ID>456</ORDER_ID>
  </ORDER>
</ORDERS>
```

Have you considered not adding the `ORDER` tag in the column?

```
DECLARE @changes TABLE (order_no VARCHAR(10), details XML)

INSERT INTO @changes VALUES ('123', NULL)
INSERT INTO @changes VALUES ('456', NULL)

UPDATE @changes 
SET details = '<ORDER_ID>' + order_no + '</ORDER_ID>'


SELECT details AS ORDER
FROM @changes
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('ORDERS')
```

Comment: Do you need it? It is a table variable so you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Well... I actually have the XML returned from a function. I want to save the XML for each order, but whereas previously I returned the XML from the function, with a root node, I was having trouble getting the XML (with the root) from the saved columns.

Comment: In my point of view, if you may change the function to output what you need, it is best to remove the 'ORDER' tag from each row. That way you keep it simple, and you do not have to query each xml to get the inner node.